# Loop over variables

Tags: r, loops, variables

I moved from Stata and have problem to match commands.
Simply, I want to loop over variables in a data frame and manipulate/analyze, like the code below. Is there a way,for example defining a temporary variable (tmp) to carry the selected variable inside the loop and be addressed directly (like dt$tmp). I appreciate your comments.

The code below loops over columns to grab variable names and labels of a dataframe.

```
#Build the dataframe
dt <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=seq(1,10,2),z=seq(1,15,3))
attr(dt$x,'label') <- "First"
attr(dt$y,'label') <- "Second"
attr(dt$z,'label') <- "Third"


#loop over variables and store names and labels in a dataframe
names<- names(dt)
vars<- data.frame(id = 1:ncol(dt),var=NA,varlab =NA)
i <- 0
for(n in names){
  i <- i + 1
  nlab <- attr(dt[[paste(n)]], 'label')
  vars$var[i] <- n
  vars$varlab[i] <- nlab
}
```

To see this:

id  var varlab

1   x   First
2   y   Second
3   z   Third

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I don't know Stata, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish either.  If you're looking for a good reference book to help you get started, I'd recommend R for Data Science (online at http://r4ds.had.co.nz/). Sometimes the problem when moving from one language to another is that the way you think about the data objects changes.  What seems trivial in one language is unheard of in another.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to interpret what you are trying to accomplish.  For example unless tmp is initially a column in df, this won't work, but it's hard for us to see your screen. If you need to define tmp as a new column you should cbind or dplyr::mutate in a new column.

If you just sketched out what you wanted it to look like that would be helpful too. You can make everything generic just help people help you.